# Illustrator: white text goes invisible

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, transparency, typesetting

I'm working with an EPS file I downloaded from the internet (a business card) and I'm editing the details. It has a background color and some text over it. If I change the text color to white, it completely disappears.

Everybody keeps saying disable the "Overprint" option, but I checked I already have this turned off.

Obviously, the text layer is above the background layer, overprint option is deselected, opacity is 100%, and other objects with white fills are visible over the background.

I know this problem has been discussed several times before, but couldn't find a useful answer.

Comment: Any blending modes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the blending mode is set to **Normal** on your text object by selecting the text and looking into the Transparency panel. In the image below, see where it says Normal. If you have anything else in that box with your text object selected, change it back to Normal.

White text set to *Multiply* or any other blending mode except *Normal* could become "invisible".

[image]

Comment: Ah yes. It was set to multiply. I feel so stupid. Thanks Lucian and Cai